# Microservice as a Webhook Client

Tags: java, webhooks, microservices

We have a server that 'publishes' its state changes in the form of webhooks invocations. What do you think is the most scaleable way to consume these webhooks payload (POST requests with JSON payload) with Java?. Thinking about using a microservices framework/library.